# how to change the 'Requires Android' version in the android market

Tags: android, version, google-play, requires

I have published an app in the android market

Strangely, even though it uses google maps, in the market it says:
Requires Android:
1.0 and up

How can I change this without messing with the manifest file? is there a way?

I have been changing the android:minSdkVersion which currently is 1, but my code is affected in strange places, crashing unexpectedly and the layouts are changed too

any ideas?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have answered your own question.

```
android:minSdkVersion
```

In your manifest controls that displayed field.

Answer (score 0):

To work with maps you also need to set API Level and SDK >= 3
maybe is that the reason of your crashes?!

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do have a problem if I change the minSdkVersion to other than "1"... For strange reasons, loading a bitmap inside a button (a custom button) crashes, while this wasn't crashing before... maybe specifying a higher sdk version loads up a lot of stuff into memory that affects my code ???

Comment: Um what Build Target did you set? 
Project (right click) -- > Properties --> Android --> Set Android 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Android [API levels](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#intro) correspond to the different releases of Android. For example, Android 1.5 (the minimum required for Maps) is API level 3. The minimum API Level is declared in the manifest as following:

```
<manifest>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
  ...
</manifest>
```